# hg export changeset

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'd like to export **only** the files that were changed in a hg changeset, to make a patch - but I'm not sure how to do this. I'm using bitbucket as a hosting service - how do I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `hg export` command actually generates a patch (in unified diff format), but also includes some extra info like the author and the commit message in case you want to use it with `hg import`.

If you just want a patch, with no extra info, generated from a changeset, it is as simple as:

```
hg diff -c REV
```

### EDIT

Since you only want the files changed in a revision, a la `hg archive` I presume, I came up with the following bourne shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p $2

for i in $(hg log -r $1 --template '{files}')
do
    mkdir -p $2/$(dirname $i)
    hg cat -r $1 $i >$2/$i
done
```

It takes two arguments: the revision to export and the directory where you want to save the files.  You could achieve the same in a similar script but using `hg archive` along with a bunch of `-I` arguments.  However, I think the proposed script is a bit more intuitive, at least to me.

**NOTE:** This script will not work correctly when files are moved or deleted from the repository.

Comment: that's almost there - I don't use diffs for making patches, probably should, but never tried. how would I get hg to just give me the files?

Comment: @danp, Try :-)...importing and exporting patches (as diffs) are built into Mercurial and is very easy.

Answer (score 2):

I just use this command:

```
hg archive -I "set:added() or modified()" -r <rev-number> -t files /path/to/directory/for/export
```